# Wrong beltline with Gates S550 on Cannondale BadBoy

Tags: compatibility, belt-drive, chainline, alfine, gates

I need to rebuild the drivetrain on a secondhand BadBoy 1 with 8-speed Alfine and Gates belt I got last year. To move house I had to disassemble the crankset because the pedals had seized, and the movers lost it so I'm not sure what exactly was in there in the first place.
[Cannondale](https://www.cannondale.com/en-us/bikes/active/urban/bad-boy/bad-boy-1) contradict themselves saying it had all CDX parts but the crankset was a Gates S150 which is in fact CDN. The sprocket was definitely not plastic so not S150, maybe the previous owner had changed it. Foolishly I got an S550 crankset, only to to find that the beltline is off by at least 1cm even if I mount the front sprocket with the dish inwards.

Figuring out what to use instead is something I'd usually gladly pay my LBS for, alas there isn't one around here. The two possibilities that look promising are either

- The apparently discontinued SRAM 4410 crankset, this sort of looks like it could have been the one used before and eBay still has it.
- A regular Alfine crank with the sprocket swapped for a Gates CT11505AA-D might work. For some reason this sprocket is sold as specific to Alfine Di2 although the [Alfine service manual](https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/sm/IHG-INTER11/SM-IHG-INTER11-003-ENG.pdf) says the mechanical and the Di2 model can have exactly the same chainline if you orient the rear sprocket right.

Any ideas or practical experiences?

Comment: My experience is that if you really want to one-shot this and just have it all work, the best thing to do is ask Gates what to get.